# Como usar o foreach com esse tipo de JSON (PHP)

Tags: php, json, array, foreach

Estou tentando exibir os valores de um JSON com PHP mais sem exito.
Código Usado:

JSON

```
{
    "friendslist": {
        "friends": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561197960265731",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 0
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561197960265738",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 0
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561197960265740",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 0
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561197960265747",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

PHP

```
$steamid_player = "76561198112612121";
        $apikey = "APIKEY";
```

```
       $amg = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=$apikey&steamid=$steamid_player&relationship=friend");
        $decode = json_decode($amg, TRUE);

        foreach ($decode["friendslist"]["friends"][0] as $valor){

            $steamid = $valor["relationship"]->steamid;

            echo $steamid;
        }
```

Erro retornado

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'relationship' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\leo\test.php on line 10

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\leo\test.php on line 10

Warning: Illegal string offset 'relationship' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\leo\test.php on line 10

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\leo\test.php on line 10

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\leo\test.php on line 10
```

Porem sempre é retornado um erro , e assim nenhum valor é exibido.
Aonde estou errando ?

Comment: Qual erro está gerando, em qual linha?

Comment: Eu passei por isso agorinha e acabei resolvendo. O que você tem que ter certeza em primeiro lugar é se o ***$decode*** está te retornando um ***array*** já que o `foreach` espera um ***array***.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segue uma simplificação, e correção de sintaxe:

```
$decode = json_decode( $amg, TRUE );
foreach ( $decode["friendslist"]["friends"] as $valor){
    $steamid = $valor["steamid"];
    echo $steamid;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/T19YnV)**.

Você estava chamando o índice `[0]` no `foreach`, sendo que ele já vai para o `$valor`. Além disso, estava tratando o retorno como objeto, sendo que o `json_decode` está retornando *array* associativa.

### Versão com objeto

Veja a diferença de sintaxe trocando o TRUE do `json_decode()`:

```
$decode = json_decode( $amg, FALSE );
foreach ( $decode->friendslist->friends as $valor){
    $steamid = $valor->steamid;
    echo $steamid;
}
```

Aqui também tem um demo no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/A8OkNl)**.

O segundo parâmetro do `json_decode` justamente determina se o retorno será um objeto ou uma *array* associativa.

Comment: Muito bom, parabéns !!!